# c++ Return string with function "Cannot overload functions by return type alone"

Tags: string, function

Im trying to let a function in C++ return string but the function name is underline in red (Visual Studio) and shows "Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone"
the string operations work fine outside of the function, but shows many errors when i place it in a function that return string.

Just learned function in lecture. Sorry I'm kind of new to C++. Just wanted to know how to return string with function properly with some string operation inside the function. Thanks

Here is part of my code:

main.cpp

```
#include"header.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    example7();
    return 0;
}
```

function.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string returnString(int a)
{
    static string str1 = " ";
    const string symbol = "!&";
    static int num;
    static int left;

    num = (a / 5);
    left = (a % 5);
    str1 = to_string(num) + symbol + to_string(left) + symbol;

    return str1;
}
int example7()
{
    static int input;
    cin >> input;

    string abc = returnString(input);
    cout << abc << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
string returnString(int a);
int example7();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` in *header.h* too, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `string` is when you declare `returnString`.

I'd suggest to turn your compiler warnings on.